# Infinite Intersection of Nested Connected Sets that are Disconnected

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, compactness, connectedness

I am working through a book in real analysis and am having trouble with a problem. I know that the following statement is false:

> If we have connected sets $S_1 \supset S_2\supset S_3\supset\cdots$, then $S=\cap\;S_n$ (the infinite intersection of all $S_n$) is connected.

However, I am not being able to find a counterexample. What is one that I could understand fairly easily?

Additionally, the next part of this asks whether this is true if the sets are also compact. I think that the statement is then true but am having a lot of trouble proving this as well.

Comment: Imagine unzipping a jacket without a back.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I'm not sure I follow on how I could obtain that from Sn?

Comment: More precisely, consider $S_n = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \large((-n, \infty) \times \{0\}\large)$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to the first part has been provided by Zhang's answer and myself in the comments.

For the compact case, suppose that $S \subseteq U \cup V$, with $U$ and $V$ disjoint open subsets of the ambient space $X \supseteq S_1$, and $U \cap S \neq \emptyset$, $V \cap S \neq \emptyset$.

(That $U$ and $V$ can be chosen to be disjoint *in $X$*, as opposed to merely disjoint in $S$, follows from compactness of $S$.)

Then $U$ and $V$ separates $S$, but it doesn't separate any $S_n$, that is, $S_n \setminus (U \cup V)$ is not empty. But the intersection, $S \setminus (U \cup V)$, is empty. This should contradict one of the characterizations of compactness that you have at your disposal.

Comment: p.s. I'm leaving the Hausdorff criterion unstated here, as the context of this question is introductory real analysis, where all spaces are metric spaces.

Comment: U and V in general cannot be chosen to be disjoint in X even when S is compact.   = {1, 2, 3} ,   = {, ∅, {3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}} and S = {1, 2}.

Comment: @am70 yes, that part requires the Hausorff criterion as well, which is automatic in metric spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A_n \subset \mathbb R^2$ be $\{x = n,\ y \in [0, 1]\}$, and $B_n$ be $(\bigcup_{m\ge n} A_m) \cup \{y = 0\} \cup \{y = 1\}$. Then each $B_n$ is connected but $\bigcap_n B_n = \{y = 0\} \cup \{y = 1\} $ is disconnected.